# Jupyter Notebook Restore Variable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, ipython, jupyter

I am running a jupyter notebook for some hours. But suddenly the kernel stuck. Now I want to restore the variable as it will take a long time to run this notebook again. The interrupt kernel is not working. Is restoring possible?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a possibility, but I also often have to struggle with long calculations in jupyter and would recommend to save important results temporarily, so that they can be reloaded quickly when starting again.